How to remove body from soap wcf after
I have  a wcf service and i have data that i want to remove it after the request already send to the wcf service, it seens that if perform dump file from the app - the data is stored there.
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://MyService/IMyService/ExecuteTestService</Action>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="54b4d03c-d765-4363-8d3a-d2bbff1053d9" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <ExecuteTestService xmlns="http://MyService">
      <Data xmlns:d4p1="http://MyService/Types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:a>123456</d4p1:a>
        <d4p1:b>654654</d4p1:b>
      </Data>
    </ExecuteTestService>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

i want to remove the Data request from the s:Body - it's possible?

I recommend that you use the Message Inspectors for this functionality.

i already try this, the problem is that the message should send the Data but should remove this after it already sent, on AfterReceiveReply i getting the response from the service - but i need to remove after BeforeSendRequest is executed..
